# Skip error and proceed execution of Mysqli::multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli, multi-query

Can I to skip errors and/or proceed execution of multi_query or I must to separate my big request and execute queries in query() individually?
I execute such operators as CREATE VIEW, CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, etc. For example, I'm not very interesting, was TABLE created, or there was some FK constraint error, or VIEW has select from other schema which not exists, etc. I just want to show error output in STDERR and execute next operator after failed or successfully completed statement.

Comment: Please elaborate a little, what errors?

Comment: Errors usually mean something; what error do you want to skip? You mean database related errors? Do they allow you to go on?

Comment: I execute such operators as CREATE VIEW, CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, etc. For example, I'm not very interesting, was TABLE created, or there was some FK constraint error, or VIEW has select from other schema which not exists, etc. I just want to execute next operator after failed or successfully completed statement.

Comment: Yes, I now that errors have their meaning, but I want to just show user error output; I can stop in a case of syntax, not logical table/view/routines structure errors.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question :)

Comment: Okay, I'll fix it now. Sorry.

Comment: try '@' sign before mysql function ???

Comment: It will skip multi_query if it will raise error. It's not the behavior I want. And I use Mysql**i**, not Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about an error raised on a query when running multi queries stops the whole execution...

Add `IGNORE`, for example

```
INSERT IGNORE into ...;
UPDATE IGNORE ...;
```

`IGNORE` will prevent the raised error from stopping the multi-query process

Comment: In DDL operators there are no IGNORE keyword (or it exists, but for other purposes).

Comment: See, might have been worthwhile mentioning DDL operators in your original question... ;)

Comment: @Guy Fawkes How? please share the fix. I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: I mean I changed my question :) In my application I only give to user 2 options: debug mode with skipping of bad queries and fast mode without skipping.